# Why don't we contract "it is" in "If it is, then..."

Tags: contractions

I wrote some instructions for a friend today, asking them to check something, and then act differently depending on the result:

> It should be spinning when it's on.  If it isn't then check the batteries.  If it is then replace the frobulator.

I used the contraction "it's" for the first sentence to replace "it is".

I didn't use the contraction for the second because I chose to contract "is not" to "isn't". However I could have chosen the opposite: "If it's not check the batteries" would have been fine.

However, the third sentence doesn't sound right if I contract "it is".  "If it's then replace the frobulator" seems incorrect.

Is there a rule that explains why "it is" shouldn't be contracted in this case, or am I wrong, and that contraction would be fine in that last sentence?

Comment: A related question which I do not know the answer to is whether the *other* contraction of `it is` is acceptable. Is "*if 'tis, then...*" good grammar? It seems plausible.

Comment: @Eric Lippert it seems to follow the description: since _is_ in _if'tis_ is there in its entirety at the end of the verb phrase. But wow I didn't know Tis was making a comeback. But I notice a lot of people writing If tis to mean If this. Or maybe that's another construction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, p.1614:

> Prepositions, auxiliaries, and infinitival *to* are stressed when they are the sole or final element in a phrase-level constituent, a PP or VP [preposition phrase or verb phrase].

Note that *be* is **always** an auxiliary verb.  In your example, *is* is an auxiliary at the end of a verb phrase:

> 1a. If it **is ___** then replace the frobulator.
>   1b. *If it**'s ___** then replace the frobulator.　　　←　*ungrammatical*

If we added the ellipted word *spinning* back in, it would no longer be at the  end of the phrase, and it would be possible to contract it:

> 2a. If it **is spinning** then replace the frobulator.
>   2b. If it**'s spinning** then replace the frobulator.

This is the same reason you can't reduce *it is* to *it's* at the end of a sentence.  *Is* needs to bear stress, so it can't be reduced to clitic form (can't be contracted).

---

*In this answer, the * symbol means that a sentence is ungrammatical.*

Comment: In: "*whose coming with us*?" "*I am*" the word *am* is *NOT* stressed - at all. As it currently stands this post is very misleading. :(

Comment: The problem as things stand is that the post seems to be confusing strong forms with stressed words. Auxiliaries have to take their strong forms if they are stressed  - or - if they are taking code. A strong form does not entail a syllable being stressed. The two things are entirely different.