# Difference Between I'm and I am

Tags: punctuation

Both

> Bob: Who are you?
>
> Joe: I'm Joe.

Or

> Bob: Who are you?
>
> Joe: I am Joe.

Is fine.

> Bob: Are you Joe?
>
> Joe: Maybe I am.

Seems fine, but

> Bob: Are you Joe?
>
> Joe: Maybe I'm.

Seems a bit weird. Is it correct to say it like that?

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26679/why-dont-we-contract-it-is-in-if-it-is-then/26680#26680

Comment: I've seen this question before; I'm sure I've: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94940/if-you-dont-do-it-ill-why-does-that-sentence-feel-so-awkward)